# Return statement inside If condition does not work in SQL Functions

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2019

I have following function to convert string to int if convertible:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[Dyve_FN_TryConvertInt](@Value varchar(18))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Value = REPLACE(@Value, ',', '')
    IF ISNUMERIC(@Value + 'e0') = 0 RETURN NULL
    IF ( CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 AND CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 1)) <> 0 ) RETURN NULL
    DECLARE @I bigint =
        CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 THEN CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 2))
        ELSE CONVERT(bigint, @Value)
        END
    IF ABS(@I) > 2147483647 RETURN NULL
    RETURN @I
END
GO
```

It worked before and after upgrading it to the following version

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019
>   13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor)

The return statement stopped returning the null value if it is not numeric. Therefore I started getting the following error:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar
 to bigint.
```

I have to add a return statement outside of ***If*** ***condition*** to return any value out of the function. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What is your input value?

Comment: You can try this SELECT dbo.[Dyve_FN_TryConvertInt] ('63d9efcd')

Comment: Doubtless a bug with the inlining of scalar UDFs

Comment: Install [Cumulative Update 4](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4548597/cumulative-update-4-for-sql-server-2019), it [fixes some bugs with scalar UDF inlining](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4538581/fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019) and it may well fix this one. Failing that, you can use `WITH INLINE = OFF` to turn off the inlining.

Comment: but anyway why aren't you using the built in try convert or try_parse function?

Comment: What's wrong with `TRY_CONVERT`? Why reinvent the wheel? `ISNUMERIC` is also a terrible function, it has so many false positives and negatives. `ISNUMERIC('.')` returns `1`, yet `CONVERT(int,'.')` will fail. `ISNUMERIC('')` will return `0` let `CONVERT(int,'')` will succeed (and there are plenty of other examples).

Comment: TRY_CONVERT is definitely a better approach, thanks for pointing out. It fixed the issue. Also, turning off inlining fixed the issue with WITH INLINE = OFF. It took me hours to figure where the actual issue is. Thank you everyone. Please feel free to post it as an answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: Cumulative Update 4 did not fix the issue fyi, I restarted my PC after this update and still the same.

Comment: I have experienced exactly same issue. To isolate the reason, i had wasted 3 hours!. FYI my SQL Server version is 15.0.2000.5..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with the inlining of Scalar UDFs in SQL Server 2019.

The execution plan looks as follows

[image]

The value passed to the function is emitted from the constant scan in the top right and aliased as  `Expr1000`. This is passed along until eventually it gets to the compute scalar that contains the following expression

```
[Expr1007]=CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('.', [Expr1000]) > ( 0 )
             THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(18), [Expr1000], 0), ( 2 )), 0)
           ELSE CONVERT(BIGINT, [Expr1000], 0)
         END
```

In the case the input is not remotely numeric this will blow up regardless of which path the `CASE` expression ends up taking.

The issue looks similar to [the one here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239432/3690). The green highlighted constant scan is under an inner join with a pass through predicate so would only be evaluated if the `ISNUMERIC` test was true. The output list for that constant scan is empty so I assume that likely the expression got moved from there with the same faulty logic as the linked answer.

You can use `WITH INLINE = OFF` to turn off inlining for that function but likely you should just remove it entirely and replace with `TRY_CONVERT` (or at least replace the body of the function with that if it is not possible to remove it entirely at this time)

Comment: I've got same error. my sql server version is SQL 2019 Standard edition, version number is 15.0.2000.xx.